# Latex Bibliography style and citation callout style

Tags: bibtex

I'm currently busy writing my masters thesis with latex and I need a certain citation style. Therefore, I used an already existing default bibliography style provided by my university. However, the citation style isn't exactly what I need. Currently, authors get cited like this: (cf. Kek et al. (2009), p. xx). I need it to look like: (cf. Kek et al. 2009, p. xx). Where do I find the respective options in my bibliography style?

I found the function:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label *
  before.all 'output.state :=
  " (" swap$ * ") " *
}
```

Erasing the curved brackets doesn't change anything (well, maybe this is due to my editor). Any ideas?

edit for MWE:

Hey guys,

thanks for your answers.

here a minimal example (I m using natbib already):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip,bibtotoc,liststotoc]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}   

    \begin{document}

     \pagenumbering{arabic} %rmische Seitennummerierung

     \section{Introduction}

     Lore ipsum dolum est blablalbalblabla  (cf. \cite{Kek}, p. 15)

     \bibliographystyle{custom_build}  %legt die zu verwendende BIBTEX-Stildatei fest
     \bibliography{lib}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your output? Changing the citation style depends on the packages you use. Your MWE should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just added the MWE; however, sorry that it took me so long, but I was nowhere near a computer.

Comment: Does the instruction `(\citealt[cf.][p.~15]{Kek})`, which I've suggested in my answer, give you the desired result?

Comment: I just tried it and it actually did! Big thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of editing the bibliography style file (not something to be done lightly!), you may want to look into using a competent citation management package that lets you generate the desired format of the citation callout directly, independently of the bibliography style you may choose to use.

Since you're using the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) citation management package, and assuming further that the key of the entry in question is "Kek", the command

```
(\citealt[cf.][p.~15]{Kek})
```

should give you the desired citation callout.